# Add delay to paginate navigate function

Tags: javascript

I am looking to add a delay to a pagination navigation function I have found so that when a user presses a forward or back button, the code will delay 600ms before actually navigating to the page.

The code that I have been focusing on is:

```
paginatelinks[i].onclick = function () {
    setTimeout(function () { instanceOfBox.navigate(this.getAttribute('rel')) }, 600)
    return false
}
```

If I add a setTimeout function of 600ms to the onClick, I get an error of 'Undefined is not a function'

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3WruL/) of the entire pagination function

Here is a snippet of the onClick function:

```
paginate.prototype.paginate_build_regularlinks = function (paginatelinks) {
var instanceOfBox = this
for (var i = 0; i < paginatelinks.length; i++) {
    var currentpagerel = paginatelinks[i].getAttribute('rel')
    if (/^(previous)|(next)|(first)|(last)$/.test(currentpagerel)) { //screen for these 'rel' values
        paginatelinks[i].onclick = function () {
            instanceOfBox.navigate(this.getAttribute('rel'))
            return false
        }
    }
    if (currentpagerel == 'previous' || paginatelinks[i].href.indexOf('previous') != -1) { //check if this is a 'previous' link
        if (!this.wraparound && this.currentpage == 0) //if current page is first page, disable 'prev' link
            paginate.setcssclass(paginatelinks[i], 'disabled', 'add')
        this.prevlinks.push(paginatelinks[i])
    }
    else if (currentpagerel == 'next' || paginatelinks[i].href.indexOf('next') != -1) { //check if this is a 'next' link
        if (!this.wraparound && this.currentpage == this.pagecount - 1) //if current page is last page, disable 'next' link
            paginate.setcssclass(paginatelinks[i], 'disabled', 'add')
        this.nextlinks.push(paginatelinks[i])
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your JSFiddle doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setTimeout is executed there is no more "this".
Try saving this in a variable and then use the variable.